# Reveal DOM element when page scrolls down 50 pixels

Tags: css, angularjs, scroll, angularjs-directive

In my Angular App, I want a DOM element to appear when the user scrolls down 50 pixels.

Is there any way to do this in Angular?

Comment: You can just use javascript for this.

Answer (score 0):

Either with javascript

```
window.pageYOffset
```

or Jquery

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

You would set them in a scroll listener like  -

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
   var x = window.pageYOffset;
   if(x >= 50){
   //apply styles
   }else{
   //remove styles
  }
 }
```

(you can use jquery for this too). Then put/take off styles to the element by checking if you're above or below 50. This is the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a directive which stores the scroll offset in a variable and use it in combination with ng-show to display and hide elements:

```
app.directive('scrollObserver', function($window) {
  return {
    scope: {
      scroll: '=scrollObserver'
    },
    link: function(scope) {
      angular.element($window).on('scroll', function(){
          scope.scroll = angular.element($window).scrollTop();

          // event listener does not trigger angular apply cycle automatically
          scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Then, you can use this directive to hide elements based on the current scroll position:

```
<span ng-show="scroll > 50" scroll-observer="scroll">Display me on scroll!</span>
```